# http 500 on ajax call in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got this ajax call :

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "/services/ged/download?pIdDocument=" + idDocument
});
```

`idDocument`has this kind of value : {3F15D23C-1E9F-678B-B865-654E5866959F}

Here's le server side rest service :

```
@Path("/ged")
@RequestScoped
public class GedRest {

    @GET
    @Path("/download/{pIdDocument}")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response downloadPdfFile(@Context HttpServletRequest pRequest, @PathParam("pIdDocument") String pIdDocument) throws AInternalException {
        // Get a pdf document
    }
}
```

I got a http 500 on the browser, and here is the server side log :

```
com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException: null for uri: http://localhost:7003/services/ged/download?pIdDocument=%7B0F90D68C-3E9F-472B-B8F5-658E5816919F%7D
```

I tried to replace - by %2D that's the same:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException: null for uri: http://localhost:7003/services/ged/download?pIdDocument=%7B0F90D68C%2D3E9F%2D472B%2DB8F5%2D658E5816919F%7D
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes see David jones answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when you are defining the route you are assigning the pIdDocument to be part of the URI and not as a GET variable.

Try this as the url in your AJAX call:

```
"/services/ged/download/" + idDocument
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "services/ged/download?pIdDocument=" + idDocument
});
```

Notice that I removed the starting **`/`** from the URl.

When a URL starts from **`/`**, it is considered from the root directory, which is **NOT** desired.

Remove the starting **`/`** from the URL and it will act as a relative URL.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. The question states he is hitting a web service so the url would be the route of the service not a document path. Also if the URL was wrong a 404 should be returned.